Flutter I Can't Find My APK File After Build
I tried generating and APK file for my android project. The build process went successfully but I can't find where to locate the APK file. Here is the message I got after the APK file was generated:
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          148.2s
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-release.apk (21.4MB)
Process finished with exit code 0

Where can I find the build folder... Is it located on the Android Studio?

The message mentions the path to the output APK.

First, go to the root directory of your project—the folder where your flutter project exists. You can open it from Android Studio by right-clicking on the app directory and then open in finder.
There should be a directory called build. If this doesn't exist or it's empty, you should regenerate the APK flutter build apk. This directory gets deleted when you run flutter clean.
Look for the app\outputs\flutter-apk directory in the build folder.


First Think Which Apk file you Need like Debug or Release, Execute this Command with your terminal:

For Debug Apk : flutter build apk --debug
For Release APk : flutter build apk --release

After that Right click with your root project name

Open in ---> Explorer ---> your app build folder ---> outputs ---> flutter apk

